# SSMS data collection reports stuck in a time warp

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, report, ssms, data-collection

While out of town, I changed the time zone on my laptop to reflect my then-current location, and happened to run several Data Collection reports in SSMS while VPN'ed into my office network.

Despite changing the time zone back again upon my return, subsequent executions of the reports still show times from the zone I'd visited.  This only happens on the laptop; if I run the same reports while remoted into the server which stores the performance data, the times are correct. I also haven't noticed any other applications on the laptop which have been similarly affected.

Anyone know how to correct this?

Comment: How are you invoking the reports? Through the online report manager? Perhaps trying clearing your browser cache to remove and stored auth cookies that might have timezone information in them and re-login to the report manager. Just a thought, no idea if that would help any.

Comment: I'm running them through Object Explorer in SSMS  -- Server\Management\Data Collection\Reports.  (I would like to port the data collection reports to Report Manager, but haven't tried that yet.)